# when hue oozie workflow failed those error logs need to store into hive table

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

Can you please someone help me to get the oozie error logs to hive table when jobs get failed. suggest me the approach how to do as i am new to this.

Comment: Can you post what you have done and researched?

Comment: Actually i am new to this. just now searching that is any default folder is there to store the logs when oozie jobs failed which is runned through hue or only we can able to see in oozie console. can u please help me.

Comment: Oozie logs are available into `/var/log/oozie` directory. If you know the workflow id, you can also use the Oozie log command to get the log for the workflow. please check the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: i did not have /var/log/oozie directory. i have only /user/userid/oozie folder in that i have only workflow numbers - workflow-1501743933.12. Even i searched log in search bar but is i dint get anything regarding log folders.

Comment: When oozie workflow failed which is runned in HUE. I can able to see those error by clicking external ID --> metadata ---> ID ---> logs ----> stderr but  can i  know where this stderr is getting stored. Can anyone help for that path.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script to pick up oozie job logs using:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000 -info <wfid>
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000 -log <wfid>
```

redirect results of it into a file, which you may load into a hive table. Then use a oozie shell action trigger this step at failure.